# Script query intervening with my datepicker

Tags: javascript

How to properly merge this 2 scripts?
Tried merging but the other one does not work properly.
E.G. The first script is my datatable design , second is my datepicker. If i delete either one , the other one works. Tried merging it also but did not work properly.

Help

Thanks

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            responsive: true
        });
    });
    </script>

    <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
```

EDITED:

This is the script of the datatables.

script_datatables.php

```
<script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables JavaScript -->
<script src="../vendor/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/datatables-plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/datatables-responsive/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
        responsive: true
    });
});
</script>
```

script_datepicker.php

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

    <script src="../vendor/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/datatables-plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/datatables-responsive/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
    <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
```

Comment: do you see any error in `console` when you merge both of it ?

Comment: @manish , when I merge both only the datatables would work if you put it on top of the datepicker , also vice versa

Comment: it's like something is conflicting between the two scripts

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function() {` does the same thing as `$( function() {`. Use

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
    responsive: true
  });
});
```

or switch their order if one depends on the other.

Comment: Can you post more context so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: What should I do sir , i removed some of my codes , now the dropdown wont work but the datepicker work.

Answer (score 0):

As CertainPerformance said, combine the two initialisations, but also ensure you've got the scripts and CSS files in the dependent order. Something like this may help:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<script src="../vendor/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/datatables-plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/datatables-responsive/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            responsive: true
        });

    });
</script>
```